# Run only specific /etc/network/if-up.d-script for specific interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, script, network-interface

I would like to run a network script when bringing up a specific interface (e.g. eth0) by invoking

```
ifup eth0
```

The script should ONLY run when bringing up eth0. My approach was to write the script (named `script.sh`) place it somewhere as executable and then write in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
up /path/to/script.sh
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that? Can I use the `/etc/network/if-up.d` scripting environment in some way? As far as I know *all* scripts in this folder will be run not no matter which interface was brought up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the scripts in ifup.d are called a huge selection of environment variables are passed to it, related to the configuration of the particular interface.  So for example, if your interface configuration looked like this.

```
iface eth0 inet manual
  dofoo on
```

Then your script would receive a variable like `$IF_DOFOO` with a value of `on`.

Knowing that you could put something at the start of your script like

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$IF_DOFOO" ] ; then
    # this script only applies to interface flagged as dofoo
    exit 0
fi
... Doing the foo.
```

With that in place, that script can easily be placed under if-up.d.

Of course you could also simply look at the `$IFACE` value, and hardcode your script to only run for a particular interface or and match it to some other external source of configuration.  Look at the other scripts in `if-up.d` for some examples of what you can do.